# An error while adding HAL Browser: Dependency 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser:' not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml, dependency-management

Trying to install the Hal Browser with Spring Boot, but I get the following error:

```
Dependency 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser:' not found
```

I wonder if there is an official reference for compatibility between Spring plugins, but anyway, here I used the latest versions by default.

Here is my POM file:

```xml
    ...
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.ec</groupId>
    <artifactId>explorecali</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>explorecali</name>
    <description>Explore California MicroService</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
```

Answer (score 9):

The package was renamed to `spring-data-rest-hal-explorer`. I verified that it's compatible with Spring Boot 2.5.6.

Maven example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-explorer</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Gradle example:

```
implementation('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-explorer')
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an incompatibility issue with the latest version of Spring, the solution is to downgrade Spring Boot to 2.3.5.RELEASE

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```